# Broadcast receiver is not registering (working) in Android Pie

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Here my code is working till Marshmallow devices but in my Pie devices it is not working.

I read a Google documentation and found remove the receiver tag from manifest and add in activity but I can't understand how to add.

Main problem is when I adding a value in offline mode its stores a value in SQLite but when come in back online mode it does not send SQLite data to server above nogout devices.

Here is my activity:

```
  broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                readFromLocalStorage();
            }
        };

     buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SubmitMethode();
//                addPremises();
                relativeLayoutAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearLayoutRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageButtonPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }


    private void SubmitMethode() {
        preName = Objects.requireNonNull(editTextPremises.getText()).toString();
        prewifiName = Objects.requireNonNull(editTextwifiName.getText()).toString();
        prewifiUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(editTextwifiUrl.getText()).toString();
        preserverUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(editTextserverUrl.getText()).toString();
        preImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
        Log.d("responseT",preName + "==" + prewifiName + "==" + prewifiUrl);

        saveToAppServer(preName, prewifiName, prewifiUrl, preserverUrl, preImage);
        editTextPremises.setText("");
        editTextwifiName.setText("");
        editTextwifiUrl.setText("");
        editTextserverUrl.setText("");
        textViewSelect.setText("Select Image");
    }

    private void readFromLocalStorage(){

        sqPremisesList.clear();
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String premisesName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_NAME));
            String premisesWifiName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_WIFI_NAME));
            String premisesWifiUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_WIFIURL));
            String premisesServerUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_SERVERURL));
            String premisesImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_IMAGEPATH));
            int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.SYNC_STATUS));


            sqPremisesList.add(new SqPremises(premisesName, premisesWifiName,
                    premisesWifiUrl, premisesServerUrl, premisesImagePath, sync_status));
        }
//
        sqPremisesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
        /*TODO: // this is new line code*/
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private void saveToAppServer(final String pName, final String pWifiName, final String pWifiUrl,
                                 final String pServerUrl, final String pImage){

        if (checkNetworkConnection()){

            progressDialog.setTitle("Adding....");
            progressDialog.setMessage("please wait while we are waiting your premises");
            progressDialog.show();

            String Url = Constant.BASE_URL + "addpremises/";

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user", userID);
            params.put("name", preName);
            params.put("wifi_name", prewifiName);
            params.put("online_url", prewifiUrl);
            params.put("offline_url", preserverUrl);
            params.put("image", preImage);
            Log.d("responseV", String.valueOf(params));


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Url, new JSONObject(params),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("responseJ", String.valueOf(response));
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                                String statusObject = response.getString("status");
                                String msgObject = response.getString("msg");

                                if (statusObject.equals("200")) {

                                    Toast.makeText(PremisesManagementActivity.this, msgObject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    saveToLocalStorage(pName, pWifiName, pWifiUrl, pServerUrl, pImage, DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK);

                                    linearLayoutAsk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    relativeLayoutAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    imageButtonPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    linearLayoutRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                             /*   String value = "false";
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("value",value);
                                editor.commit();*/

                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(PremisesManagementActivity.this, msgObject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                linearLayoutAsk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                                imageButtonPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                                linearLayoutRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                                relativeLayoutAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    saveToLocalStorage(pName, pWifiName, pWifiUrl, pServerUrl, pImage, DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);

                                }
                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                    error.printStackTrace();
                    saveToLocalStorage(pName, pWifiName, pWifiUrl, pServerUrl, pImage, DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);

                }
            });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

//            MySingleton.getInstance(PremisesManagementActivity.this).addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest);
        }else {
            saveToLocalStorage(pName, pWifiName, pWifiUrl,
                    pServerUrl, pImage, DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
        }


    }
 private void saveToLocalStorage (String pName, String pWifiName, String pWifiUrl,
                                     String pServerUrl,String pImage, int sync){

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(pName, pWifiName, pWifiUrl, pServerUrl, pImage,  sync , sqLiteDatabase);
        readFromLocalStorage();
        dbHelper.close();

    }
//
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DBContact.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST));

//            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DBContact.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST);
//            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, null);
//            sendBroadcast();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
```

And it is receiver which is add on manifest file:

```
  <receiver android:name=".utils.NetworkMonitor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And here I am adding my Network monitor file:

```
if (checkNetworkConnection(context)){
            final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            final SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.SYNC_STATUS));
                if (sync_status == DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED){

                    final String premisName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_NAME));
                    final String premisWifiName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_WIFI_NAME));
                    final String premisWifiUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_WIFIURL));
                    final String premisServerUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_SERVERURL));
                    final String premisesImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.PREMISES_IMAGEPATH));



                    String Url = Constant.BASE_URL + "addpremises/";

                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("user", userID );
                    params.put("name", premisName);
                    params.put("wifi_name", premisWifiName);
                    params.put("online_url", premisWifiUrl);
                    params.put("offline_url", premisServerUrl);
                    params.put("image",premisesImagePath);
                    Log.d("responseV", String.valueOf(params));

                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Url, new JSONObject(params),
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    Log.d("responseJ", String.valueOf(response));

                                    try {
                                        String statusObject = response.getString("status");
                                        String msgObject = response.getString("msg");

                                        if (statusObject.equals("200")) {
                                            dbHelper.updateLocalDatabase(premisName, premisWifiName, premisWifiUrl,
                                                    premisServerUrl, premisesImagePath, DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK, sqLiteDatabase);

                                            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DBContact.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST));
                                        }
                                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("responseE", String.valueOf(error.getMessage()));
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                }
            }


        }

    }

    public boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context){

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }
```

How can I solve this problem? I am a beginner to broadcast receiver.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue related to network call on some project for Android Pie only.

If you are getting issue related to Network call, please add  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This might fix your issue for Pie.

Comment: i have been already added in my code and this line of code is working for volley request error on pie devices.

Comment: there are nothing in error but the code is not working.